# HBase is not starting in windows

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to use HBase in windows and I am new to it. I am getting the following errors while I was trying to run the file start-hbase.cmd

```
C:\Users\tb\Desktop\GA_Works\hbase-1.0.0\bin>start-hbase.cmd
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1000m "
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode.
```

What's the reason of these errors. I can't see HBase running at http://localhost:60010

Answer (score 0):

If that error message *really* says:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1000m "
```

I would examine the `start-hbase.cmd`, along with the other ones it calls, to see if there's a funny character in them. In particular, `hbase.cmd` is the one called to determine the startup mode and set the default maximum heap size.

I would suggest, for debugging purposes, you temporariliy place:

```
echo %java_arguments%
```

into that script, just before the invocation of `java`, to see what arguments are actually being passed.

The quote character at the end, and the error message itself, seem to indicate that it's being considered part of the memory size specification, despite the fact there *appears* to be a space between them.

The other possibility is your `HBASE_HEAPSIZE` environment variable which is used to override the default. It may be that you've set that incorrectly, it should be nothing for than the numeric value (for example, `100` if you wanted `-Xmx100m` as one of the Java options).